# .Net MVC: need to display a list of users from AspNetUser table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Very new to .Net MVC.  Looking for a way to display the contents of the AspNetUser table on a page for authorized users to view.  Created a model, and a Controller with views. The problem is that the connection to this table is already open, and I am having a hard time figuring out how to reference that connection instead of creating a new ApplicationDbContext() (which of course returns an error.) Please help!  Code below:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PanoramaPoint.Models;

namespace PanoramaPoint.Controllers
{
    public class AspNetUsersController : Controller
    {

            private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


        // GET: AspNetUsers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.AspNetUsers.ToList());
        }
```

How do I reference and existing ApplicationDbContext instead of creating a new one?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean.  What's wrong with the code shown?  In what way is it failing?

Comment: Why do you need to access the existing one?  This is pretty standard disconnected functionality.  It looks correct to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, everyone, I figured it out.  It is the Identities table I was trying to display, and that was the problem.  I just have to find a different way to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework (and ADO.Net, for that matter) use what is called Connection Pooling.  When you request a new connection, it isn't actually going out and making that new connection.  Behind the scenes, it pulls an existing connection from a pool of already connected resources.

Your request to use an already existing connection is handled for you by Entity Framework.  Don't worry about it.  Your code is fine the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, everyone, I figured it out.  It is the Identities table I was trying to display, and that was the problem.  I just have to find a different way to display it.